# NEO4J gives node count as negative

Tags: neo4j, nodes, graph-databases

I have ingested some data in neo4j.All the created nodes have two labels master_node and ICICI but when I run following it gives a negative number (-901)[image]

```
match(n:ICICI) return count(n)
```

and when I add the other label.it gives me count of nodes for a different label.

```
match(n:master_node:ICICI) return count(n)
```

and when try to fetch nodes using

```
match(n:ICICI) return n
```

I get the following response
[image]

and when I try to fetch data using both the labels.it gives me data related to different label

```
match(n:master_node:ICICI) return n;
```

[image]

if u observe carefully that last node has three labels OperatingSystem,master_node but I Queried with labels master_node and ICICI.

Using Neo4j:3.5.14

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which neo4j version are you running?

Comment: 3.5.14 community

Comment: If possible, try upgrading to latest version. Or if you need to use `3.5`, try upgrading to `3.5.21`.